# Поиск по ListActivity

Tags: java, android

Как добавить `ActionBar` в `ListActivity` и сделать в нем `SearchWidget`, вернее выполнить поиск элементов по списку(как поиск в плей маркете)?

Код ListActivity:

```
 public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
String data[] = new String[]{"Элемент1", "Элемент2", "Элемент3", 
"Элемент4","Элемент5"};

int images[] = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
        R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    List<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("keyText", data[i]);
        hm.put("keyImage", Integer.toString(images[i]));
        list.add(hm);
    }
    String[] from = {"keyImage", "keyText"};

    int[] to = {R.id.image1, R.id.text1};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.item_list, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    chooseActivity(position);
}


private void chooseActivity(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityName.class));
            break;
           //...
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы экшенбар появился в `ListActivity`, в качестве темы приложения необходимо использовать одну из *Holo* или *Material* (для API21 и выше) тем с экшенбаром, например `android:Theme.Holo`.

Создаем меню с виджетом поиска (*res/menu/main_menu.xml*):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

в код активити добавляем метод обработки экшенбара и поиска:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchView.clearFocus();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

объект `adapter` выносим в поле класса, чтобы к нему имелся доступ в методе меню:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
        ...
    }
}
```